# How to update the kernel from 2.6.16 on Debian squeeze?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, dependencies, debian-squeeze

I just did an update of my Debian system on my vserver from lenny to squeeze as described [here](http://www.go2linux.org/how-to-upgrade-from-debian-lenny-to-squeeze).

I got some errors during the install, saying that glibc couldn't be updated.

I did an `apt-get -f install`, which gives me the following warning:

> WARNING: this version of the GNU libc requires kernel version
>   2.6.18 or later. Please upgrade your kernel before installing
>   glibc.
>
> The installation of a 2.6 kernel *could* ask you to install a new libc
>   first, this is NOT a bug, and should *NOT* be reported. In that case,
>   please add lenny sources to your /etc/apt/sources.list and run:
>     apt-get install -t lenny linux-image-2.6
>   Then reboot into this new kernel, and proceed with your upgrade
>
> dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.10.2-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
>    subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.10.2-2_i386.deb

I added these lines to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian-volatile squeeze/volatile main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian-security squeeze/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian lenny main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates main contrib non-free
```

Now I tried to install a newer kernel using this command:

```
apt-get install linux-image-2.6-openvz-686
```

Which leads to this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libc-bin: Breaks: libc6 (< 2.10) but 2.7-18lenny2 is to be installed
  linux-image-2.6-openvz-686: Depends: linux-image-2.6.26-2-openvz-686 
  but it is not going to be installed
  locales: Depends: glibc-2.10-1
  nscd: Depends: libc6 (> 2.10) but 2.7-18lenny2 is to be installed
```

#### Question:

What do I have to do to upgrade my kernel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the kernel upgrade isn't possible because I'm running a virtual machine inside a virtual server (openvz).

I think for a kernel upgrade the server itself has to upgrade the kernel.

Comment: ahh.  this would have been important info to add to the initial question.  yes, you can't upgrade a VPS' kernel -- you have to upgrade the server's kernel.

Comment: I had the same problem at a VM on server4you.de while upgrading from squeeze to wheezy but the server has kernel 2.6 installed. I had to move to a new VM on a mashine that has a  newer kernel

Answer (score 2):

I guessed that you couldn't upgrade because you were working within a vps, and you discovered that yourself.  It is possible to run different versions of the kernel on a vps from the server root, but that can only be done from the root.

See my question [Debian Lenny expects udev on a vps that doesn’t support it](https://superuser.com/questions/109913/debian-lenny-expects-udev-on-a-vps-that-doesnt-support-it): even though Debian might complain about some unmet dependencies, you might still have introduced code that depends in some way on the higher version of Linux you haven't got: check to see if `udev` is installed; there might be others.