# Debian Lenny expects udev on a vps that doesn't support it

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, debian, xen, udev

Primary symptom: `/proc/self/fd` is there and normally populated, however `/dev/fd` is not.  Process substitution therefore fails, because bash wants to create files under `/dev/fd`.

`/dev/.static/` and `/dev/.udev` are populated.  `aptitude udev` shows that the Debian package is installed, even though udev cannot be supported on this Xen vps (and, I believe, isn't supported by default until later stable versions of the Linux kernel).

Host:

```
Linux version 2.6.16.29-xen (root@potige) (gcc version 4.1.2 20061028 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-19)) #1 SMP Tue Dec 5 20:43:23 CET 2006
```

The Debian inst. is an up-to-date Lenny 5.0.4.

**Question**

I can solve the immediate problem by symlinking from `proc/self/fd` to `/dev/fd`, and putting the appropriate script in init.d.  But are there any risks arising from Debian being misinformed about what my vps can do?  And if so, what should I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Xen HowTos I've seen ([HowToForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-xen-on-debian-lenny-amd64), [debian.org](http://wiki.debian.org/Xen#AdditionalnotefordomUonlennyusingxen-tools)) indicate that *udev* needs to be enabled at image creation by passing `--role=udev` to `xen-create-image`.

I doubt you can create an image that uses *udev* on a running system that doesn't support it, but it might be possible.

[My best guess](http://lists.gllug.org.uk/pipermail/gllug/2009-April/077500.html) is that you should ***remove*** the *udev* package from your Lenny guest (`apt-get remove udev`), and let it use the old *devfs*.  If you have packages that depend on *udev*, you may need to remove them and find alternatives that do not.

Comment: Accepted: the link is spot on.  I have emailed my vps provider, who understands the issue, but is in no hurry to upgrade the Xen server.