# "Booting" a lxc machine hangs

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, lxc

When I try to "boot" a lxc (linux container) machine it hangs on hardware detection. Can this be solved without removing the hardware detection from the boot sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that udev can't be used in a LXC container. [See here about Karmic in LXC](http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/lxc-configure-ubuntu-karmic-containers/)

Comment: related (not specific to ubuntu or lxc): http://superuser.com/questions/109913/debian-lenny-expects-udev-on-a-vps-that-doesnt-support-it